# Light Shows in Europe

Tags: europe, sightseeing, destinations

Any recommendations on light, fire, illuminated art, etc. shows in Europe that are at least as impressive as Lyon's [Fête des lumières](http://www.fetedeslumieres.lyon.fr)?  ([images](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=fete+de+lumiere&tbm=isch&biw=1216&bih=603), [more](http://www.metafilter.com/110643/Playable-Pinball-Projection))

I'm after impressive city-wide-ish shows, not simple laser shows on the side of only one building.  I'd slightly prefer fall stuff, but whenever.

Answer (score 6):

You may enjoy *[Rhein in Flammen](http://www.rhein-in-flammen.com/)* (Rhine in Flames), a festival taking place annually from May to September along beautiful sections of the Rhine, with fireworks and ships with a lot of lights.

It strolls along the Rhine river valley, passing by wineyards, castles, cities, forests, lakes...

You can find a bit of information on its [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhein_in_Flammen), especially in [the German version](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhein_in_Flammen) if you can read it.

[image: A part of the trip]

[A page of a German fan of fireworks](http://www.feuerwerk-kalender.de/dbfwkalender/index.php) gives you [the German highlights](http://www.feuerwerk-kalender.de/dbfwkalender/hilights/index.php) too ([including Rhein in Flammen](http://www.feuerwerk-kalender.de/dbfwkalender/rheininflammen/index.php)), as well as [a calender of fireworks events in Germany](http://www.feuerwerk-kalender.de/dbfwkalender/monate/monat.php).

Answer (score 5):

On the National Holiday in Liechtenstein on August 15, there is always a huge firework for 40 to 50 minutes. The firework is launched from the Prince's castle, but it is visible in half of the country. If you're in the center of Vaduz it is really great, since the lights are following directly down on you. And you won't be alone, since there are around 20'000 to 30'000 people coming to see it. (The country has only 35'000 inhabitants.)

To make the event even better, there are a lot of different bars, food corners, and other shows during the whole night.

And to make the day really great, you should be aware that in the morning there is free wine and beer for everyone next to the Prince's castle.

I added some picture of the firework so that you get an impression:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The [Tsarevets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsarevets) (Царевец) hill in Veliko Tarnovo, Bulgaria, is a mediaeval stronghold from XII-XIV century. It has been the seat of the Bulgarian kingdom during that period and a large portion of the castle wall and some buildings have been found. It offers a great view to the city and the surroundings, and to your question, there is a "Light and Sound" audiovisual display which depicts scenes and events from Bulgarian history from this time period. It's on display during the summer months

[image]
<sub>[Image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Tsarevets_zvuk_i_svetlina.jpg) from Wikipedia, licensed under [CC-BY 2.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/deed.en)</sub>

It is a remarkable experience, even if I do say so myself as a Bulgarian.

Comment: "Light and sound" takes place many times in a year, but the biggest one is on 22nd of March, during the celebration of the Veliko Tarnovo's Holiday. There also a lot of fireworks and it's free to watch from the entry of Tsaretets. It's also free to watch on 3rd of March, 6th and 22nd of September and some other Bulgarian holidays, but without fireworks. Groups(between 32 and 100 persons) can make a reservation and watch the  audio-visual show at every time, but it costs 800BGN (400 EUR)

Answer (score 3):

Nothing is as good as Lyon's Fete des Lumières!

haha just kidding, but yeah I can't think of something of the same type.

Maybe [Cannes's pyrotechnical festival](http://www.festival-pyrotechnique-cannes.com/rubrique.php3?id_rubrique=2): It's fireworks that are particularly sophisticated, the place is usually crowded so it's probably good. There are [videos on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=cannes+pyrotechni%2a&oq=cannes+pyrotechni%2a)

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking for something a bit more than simply fireworks, but that's worth knowing about too.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Las Fallas (Els Falles) in Valencia](http://www.fallasfromvalencia.com/), Spain. It's a week long party, with [huge displays of fireworks](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FWfeLGYTO0s), and ends with La Cremà [(video)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0JoMTcmkVF8):

> Formerly, much time would be spent by the Casal faller preparing the
>   ninots (Valencian for puppets or dolls). During the week leading up to
>   March 19, each group takes its ninot out for a grand parade, and then
>   mounts it, each on its own elaborate firecracker-filled cardboard and
>   paper-mâché artistic monument in a street of the given neighbourhood.
>   This whole assembly is a falla.
>
> [...]
>
> On the final night of Falles, around midnight on March 19, these
>   falles are burnt as huge bonfires. This is known as the cremà (the
>   burning), and this is of course the climax of the whole event, and the
>   reason why the constructions are called falles ("torches").
>   Traditionally, the falla in the Plaça de l'Ajuntament is burned last.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar looking [festival of lights](http://www.berlin.de/kultur-und-tickets/events/festival_of_lights_berlin/index.en.php) in Berlin from 10 to 21 October, not sure if how it compares to Lyon's Fête des lumières, but probably fairly similar.